How can I change the edge colour in a ggdag_classic object?
I thought this would be simple but I can't seem to crack it. I'm using the ggdag package in r to draw a DAG. I would like to change the colour (or transparency) of all of the edges in the DAG.
Using the example from the ggdag_classic help file:
dag <- dagify(
  y ~ x + z2 + w2 + w1,
  x ~ z1 + w1,
  z1 ~ w1 + v,
  z2 ~ w2 + v,
  w1 ~ ~w2
)

ggdag_classic(dag, text_col="grey") +
  theme_dag()

This changes the colour of the text, but I would like to change the edge colour as well.
I thought that geom_dag_edges might help but this only adds an extra set of edges resulting in a double arrow, and scale_edge_colour_manual appears to do nothing.
It might be that re-creating the ggdag_classic using the other functions within the package is easiest way but I tried doing this using the source code (https://rdrr.io/cran/ggdag/src/R/ggdag.R) but couldn't build a plot that matched that of ggdag_classic

If you start with your original plot:
p <- ggdag_classic(dag, text_col="grey") +
  theme_dag()

p


You can remove the existing edges
ss <- unlist(lapply(p$layers, function(i) class(i$geom)[1] != 'GeomDAGEdgePath'))
p$layers <- p$layers[ss]

Now you are free to add whichever type of edges you like:
p + geom_dag_edges(edge_color = 'red')



Thanks, it almost works perfectly but the length of the edges changes slightly. You can see in your pictures that the black lines are longer that the red ones, but I'm finding the red ones are longer than the back ones and are overlapping with the node titles. Is there a way to draw the same edges but in a different colour?

For anyone who find this in the future, the below gives the same edges as the ggdag_classic:
'geom_dag_edges_link(ggplot2::aes(
start_cap = ggraph::label_rect(name),
end_cap = ggraph::label_rect(to)
))'
